# is there any way to get grafana dashboard time range "timeline" from database

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Is there any way to get Grafana dashboard time range "timeline" from database, an influxdb one.

Something like `$X` , `$Y` their values are in influx db.

```
&from=$Y&to=$Y
```